# Teams Sample Calling BOT does not update participants

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am running the sample from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/microsoft-teams-samples/calling-and-meeting-bot-sample-v4/

Which allows Teams calls to be made to and from a BOT.

It all works fine and I can see there are /callback events firing for the state changes in the calls.  For example a request to call a user results in the user being called at his Teams application, and the states of the call being updated in the BOT
from Establishing->Established and then to
Terminated when one end hangs the call up.

However the Participants collection of the call is not being set.  There is no participant information in the callback JSON, and if I try to poll for participants using :

```
graphServiceClient.Communications.Calls[callid].Participants
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();
```

that collection comes back as null.

I need to put one of the call parties on Hold and cannot do this without a participant id.

What am I missing ?
Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Have you tried using Graph API call?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-getting-a-group-call

Comment: yes. Please see the original question.