# How to port Teams Call BOT Sample code to Beta API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am running the sample from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/microsoft-teams-samples/calling-and-meeting-bot-sample-v4/ which allows Teams calls to be made to and from a BOT using the version 1.0 API

There are some features which do not appear to work (in particular Participation Notifications) and there is a good chance that this feature was added in the /beta API (see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog/?filterBy=Cloud%20communications,beta&page=3#)

I would therefore like to port the sample application to use the beta API but have run into a number of issues when switching nuget packages.

The V1.0 solution runs with the following packages

```
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core" Version="4.15.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Client" Version="1.2.0.4161" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Core" Version="1.2.0.4161" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="2.0.8" />
```

When I add the Microsoft.Graph.Beta package, naturally I get a lot of "ambiguous" fixup errors because the calls API is duplicated.

The only way of resolving this ambiguity is to remove both

```
Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Client, 
and
Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Core
```

I then have a number of unresolved function references which primarily are looking for functions in those removed namespaces, but have not been provided with the Beta namespace

For example :

```
Error   CS0426  The type name 'User' does not exist in the type 'Configuration'     
Error   CS0426  The type name 'Users' does not exist in the type 'Configuration'    
Error   CS1729  'ObjectRoot' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments  
Error   CS1061  'string' does not contain a definition for 'NotNullOrWhitespace'    
Error   CS1061  'AuthenticationProvider' does not contain a definition for 'GraphLogger'
Error   CS0103  The name 'HttpConstants' does not exist in the current context      
Error   CS1061  'OnlineMeeting' does not contain a definition for 'JoinWebUrl'      
Error   CS0426  The type name 'User' does not exist in the type 'Configuration'     
Error   CS1061  'IdentitySet' does not contain a definition for 'GetPrimaryIdentity'    
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'GraphLogger' could not be found         
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IGraphLogger' could not be found
```

Can anyone suggest what is the correct procedure to update this sample to use the Beta API ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if that sample is capable of updating to use Graph Beta API. The new beta API could possibly have changes that is not compatible with this sample?

Comment: It seems like the sample is not compatible with Graph Beta API. And also, it is not a good practice to use Beta API in production as its subjected to change.

Comment: Prasad, thank you for your comment, I am aware that the Beta is subject to change, but am trying to investigate why participant callbacks are not working with the version 1.0 API.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468684/teams-sample-calling-bot-does-not-update-participants

Comment: Have you tried using Graph API call? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-getting-a-group-call

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Beta and V1.0 API in same project like below:

```
namespace Microsoft.Teams.Apps.ABC
{
    extern alias BetaLib;

    using System;
    using Microsoft.Graph;
    using Beta = BetaLib::Microsoft.Graph;

    public class GraphServiceABC : IGraphServiceABC
    {
        private readonly Beta.IGraphServiceClient betaServiceClient;
        private readonly IGraphServiceClient serviceClient;
      
        public GraphServiceABC(
            Beta.IGraphServiceClient betaServiceClient,
            IGraphServiceClient serviceClient)
        {
            this.betaServiceClient = betaServiceClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(betaServiceClient));
            this.serviceClient = serviceClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceClient));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Which nuget packages are required for this, and does an alias need to be set somewhere ?

Comment: If suppose you are trying with any Beta & V1.0 both, then you can create the alias like above and can use it without any ambiguity.